# Cognos 10.2 Creating Predefined filters in Framework Manager

Tags: filter, db2, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

I have to create a custom pre-defined filter in cognos Framework.
Filters follows the below logic.

```
AND I_CLM_SAN NOT IN 
(
SELECT I_CLM_SAN FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS A1,I_CLM_SAN FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT C_CLM_STAT,I_CLM_SAN FROM DLROB.SVC_CLM) 
WHERE C_CLM_STAT = 'R' OR C_CLM_STAT = 'X' GROUP BY I_CLM_SAN)  WHERE A1 > 1
)
```

Basically, in database Claim San (I_CLM_SAN) is been updating two times for Claim  status (C_CLM_STAT ) X and R flags, for that we have to exclude those san which are repeated. i wont able to make this sql in framework filter.

Please address, if someone has better solution on this..

Comment: What is your question? Maybe explain why you "wont able to make this sql in framework filter".  why won't you be able to do that?

Comment: I have to deliver an adhoc package to user,where I have to create one filter in it .. I can manage  this Sql filter in reporting side...,but could not able to make it in FM level...